# Printing to file works on Linux but not on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, file, python-3.x, output

So I wrote this code and it works perfectly fine on Linux.

1. Reading data from file
2. Do whatever my code is supposed to do
3. Write the solutions on a new file.

Here's the part of the code that is supposed to do that:

```
outFile = open( "input.txt", "w" )

for item in oplist:
     outFile.write(item + "\n")

outFile.close
```

It works perfectly fine on Linux but on windows in only creates the new output file but doesn't write anything into it.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not *closing* the file; you are merely referring to the close method. Call it:

```
outFile.close()
```

Without closing the file buffers won't be flushed until Python exits.

A better way to handle file closing is to use the `with` statement:

```
with open( "input.txt", "w" ) as outFile:
    for item in oplist:
        outFile.write(item + "\n")
```

Now the file is closed automatically.

Comment: Good catch! I totally glossed over the missing `()` when I read the post. Although, wouldn't the buffer get flushed when the script finishes, anyways?

Comment: Ohh thanks for the answer. It's usually the small mistakes that kill me while programming. Forgot the brackets *_*

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: yes, it does, but I am guessing the OP did *not* close the file. There writing itself otherwise looks fine, and on Windows a still open file behaves differently as well.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget The buffer DID flush when the script finished :)